# how install asterisk in Unix

Tags: solaris

I get an error
:
`bash-3.2# gmake install`
.....

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/asterisk-1.4.2/sounds'
--2015-03-19 20:19:38-- http://ftp.digium.com/pub/telephony/sounds/releases/asterisk-moh-FREEPLAY-wav.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.digium.com... failed: node name or service name not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `ftp.digium.com'
gmake[1]: *** /var/opt/asterisk/moh/.asterisk-moh-FREEPLAY-wav Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/asterisk-1.4.2/sounds'
gmake: *** [datafiles] Error 2
```

Comment: Or network connection has problem or your machine can't resolve domain , if you have ping of 8.8.8.8, manipulate /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I tested with `nslookup` and it is a sad fact that `ftp.digium.com` does not exist as a domain name, at least not at the time of this writing. I tested and found that `www.digium.com` DOES exist. I went further to see if my browser would download from `http://www.digium.com/pub/telephony/sounds/releases/asterisk-moh-FREEPLAY-wav.tar.gz` - but it gives me an error 404 (file not found).

Comment: Asterisk 1.4.x reached [End Of Life](http://blogs.digium.com/2012/03/16/asterisk-1-4-eol/) in 2012. Please throw yours away and get a newer version from http://www.asterisk.org/.